# window.setInterval - is it possible to have more than one? how?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have created a slideshow widget, using jQuery.UI widgets that works with window.setInterval.
I am trying to have more than one slideshow in the same page and i get the following results:

- If I try invoking the same widget for both of my divs with images:

  ```
  $('#div1').slideshow();  
  $('#div2').slideshow();
  ```

  none of them work;
- I have cloned the definition of my widget and named it slideshowsmall

  ```
  $('#div1').slideshow();  
  $('#div2').slideshowsmall();
  ```

and only the second one works.

my widget code is in this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/12uw44Ws), but i really think the problem, at least in the second try, has to do with setInterval

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your widget code when **setInterval** calls the ChangeLeft/Right.. method the **slideshowdiv** variable always points to the last element on which slideShow is called. the reason for this is the way you are invoking change methods which is not adviceable.

Please use the below code to call your change method it should solve your problem. You will notice I am passing the **slideshowdiv** object to change methods.

```
this.options.timer = window.setInterval(function () {
                ChangeImageLeft(velocidade, slideshowdiv);
            }, intervalo);
```

Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 3):

Having multiple `setInterval()` by itself cannot be causing problems. It is more likely to have something to do with the code it's executing (and your widget code being non-english makes it very hard to analize and comprehend).

`setInterval()` returns and integer ID of the "interval", so that you can later `clearInterval(...)` by passing this ID. This scenario was implemented exactly for multi-interval uses. More details on [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setInterval)

Comment: i'm sorry mkilmanas, but i will have to attribute my answer to ShankarSangoli. thank you very much